# Javascript remove characters utill 3 slash /

Tags: javascript

Whats the best to way, based on the input below, to get everything in the url after the domain:

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com.uk/sadsad/asdsadsad/asdasdasda/?asda=ggy";
var url = "http://www.domain.com.uk/asdsadsad/asdasdasda/#45435";
var url = "http://www.domain.com.uk/asdasdasda/?324324";
var url = "http://www.domain.com.uk/asdasdasda/";
```

The output:

```
url = "/sadsad/asdsadsad/asdasdasda/?asda=ggy";
url = "/asdsadsad/asdasdasda/#45435";
url = "/asdasdasda/?324324";
```

UPDATE: the domain its not always the same. (sorry)

Thx

Comment: Any reason not to do `s.replace('http://www.domain.com.uk', '')`?

Comment: yeh, development server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every absolute URL consists of a protocol, separated by two slashes, followed by a host, followed by a pathname. An implementation can look like:

```
// Search for the index of the first //, then search the next slash after it
var slashOffset = url.indexOf("/", url.indexOf("//") + 2);
url = url.substr(slashOffset);
```

Comment: `https://username:password@www.domain.co.uk:8080/path/morepath/file.html#anchor?param=value`

Comment: @StephenP Why did you add that comment? My method will return `/path/morepath/file.html#anchor?param=value`. Not sure why you've swapped the query string and hash.

Comment: It was (supposed to be) just an example of a more complex case - but since I blew it an put the hash in the wrong place I should delete it. tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You should really parse the URI.

http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/parseuri/js/

Comment: I really dont think adding a url parser plugin (that will increase my page size) its the best way to achieve this. I think a plugin only pay the size con in two situations: if what you need, in terms of functionality, its covered up by the plugin or framework and it take to many time to be writen again (time you dont have), or if you gonna face some complicated problems already solved by the plugin or framework.

Answer (score 1):

If the domain is always the same, a simple replace will work fine:

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com.uk/sadsad/asdsadsad/asdasdasda/?asda=ggy";
var afterDomain = url.replace("^http://www.domain.com.uk/", "");
```

You could also use RegEx:

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com.uk/sadsad/asdsadsad/asdasdasda/?asda=ggy";
var afterDomain = url.replace(/^[^\/]*(?:\/[^\/]*){2}/, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is in the browser, creating an anchor element will do a lot of magic on your behalf:

```
var a=document.createElement('a');
a.href="http://somedomain/iouhowe/ewouho/wiouhfe?jjj";
alert(a.pathname + a.search + a.hash); //   /iouhowe/ewouho/wiouhfe?jjj
```

Comment: the output comes without the first slash